# Cauchy Thoerem for not bounded region, what means $f(\infty)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $\gamma$ be a Jordan Curve and $f$ a holormorphic function in Ext($\gamma$), at $\infty$ and along $\gamma$. Prove that

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw = f(\infty) - f(z)$ if $ z \in Ext(\gamma)$

and

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw = f(\infty)$ if $ z \in Int(\gamma)$

i dont know how to proceed, Cauchy Theorem say that

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw = 0$ if $ z \in Ext(\gamma)$

and

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw = f(z)$ if $ z \in Int(\gamma)$

if $\gamma$ is any closed curve, so what should i do about that $f(\infty)$?